# How to connect a XSL stylesheet to a XML file to produce HTML?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for over a week now, and nothing seems to be working. I've made sure that I have referenced the XSL file in XML as well.I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong but I would really appreciate some help from someone who knows about this type of syntax. I'm new to XML so go easy guys!

Here is my code so far:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="Question2.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<!DOCTYPE patronRecord [
  <!ELEMENT patronRecord (Item*)>
  <!ATTLIST patronRecord firstName CDATA #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST patronRecord lastName CDATA #REQUIRED>
  <!ELEMENT Item (title,Authors,callNumber,due,overdue)>
  <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT Authors (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT callNumber (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT due (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT overdue (#PCDATA)>
]>
<patronRecord firstName="John" lastName="Smith">
   <Item>
      <title>Wireless network security</title>
      <Authors>T.Wrightson</Authors>
      <callNumber>212.12/56</callNumber>
      <due>26-12-2016</due>
      <overdue>NO</overdue>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <title>T. Tao</title>
      <Authors>Analysis</Authors>
      <callNumber>515/305</callNumber>
      <due>23-12-2016</due>
      <overdue>NO</overdue>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <title>The art of computer programming</title>
      <Authors>D.E. Knuth</Authors>
      <callNumber>005.1/300</callNumber>
      <due>25-11-2016</due>
      <overdue>YES</overdue>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <title>Python for dummies</title>
      <Authors>S. Maruch and A. Ranum</Authors>
      <callNumber>145.3/57</callNumber>
      <due>01-10-2016</due>
      <overdue>YES</overdue>
   </Item>
</patronRecord>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/patronRecord">
      <html>
         <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="Item">
               <xsl:value-of select="title" />
               <br />
               <xsl:value-of select="Authors" />
               <br />
               <xsl:value-of select="callNumber" />
               <br />
               <xsl:value-of select="due" />
               <br />
               <xsl:value-of select="overdue" />
               <br />
            </xsl:for-each>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In what way does your attempt fail, in what way do the answers to your previous question's duplicate not help?

Comment: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///Users/benharrington/Documents/UNI/CSIT128/Assignment%206/Question2.xsl. (Reason: CORS request not http)." @MartinHonnen

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome has disallowed any reference to file URI based XSLT for many years and Firefox has done so recently, too. So you will need to load XML and XSLT over HTTP(S), for instance from a local web server installation. In the case of Chrome there is also a command line option to explicitly allow the file access. I think IE still allows it, not sure about Edge in the future where they intend to move to Chromium's rendering engine.

Comment: Recommend transforming server side to avoid all the browser confusion.